# Chart.js: Runtime errors when setting legend position to "left" or "right"

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js

Chart.js throws runtime errors for the chart options is `null` whenever I change the legend position from "top" to "left" or "right". I am using the latest version, `v4.4.0`, and creating the pie chart in an Angular project.

```js
  @ViewChild('chartPie') private _chartPie: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>;

  public chart: Chart<'pie'>;

  public pieChartData = [
    { year: 2010, count: 10 },
    { year: 2011, count: 20 },
    { year: 2012, count: 45 },
  ];

  constructor(private zone: NgZone) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    Chart.register(...registerables);
  }

  public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this._initChart();
  }

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.chart) this.chart.destroy();
  }

  private _initChart() {
    const ctx = this._chartPie.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
    this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      this.chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
          labels: this.pieChartData.map((d) => d.year),
          datasets: [
            {
              label: 'Acquisitions by year',
              data: this.pieChartData.map((d) => d.count),
            },
          ],
        },
        options: {
          responsive: true,
          plugins: {
            legend: {
              display: true,
              position: 'right', // "top/bottom" works fine
            },
            title: {
              display: true,
              text: 'Chart.js Pie Chart',
            },
          },
        },
      });
    });

    // this.chart.update();
  }
```

[image]

Chart.js function where error is getting thrown:

```js
 inRange(chartX, chartY, useFinalPosition) {
        const point = this.getProps([
            'x',
            'y'
        ], useFinalPosition);
        const { angle , distance  } = getAngleFromPoint(point, {
            x: chartX,
            y: chartY
        });
        const { startAngle , endAngle , innerRadius , outerRadius , circumference  } = this.getProps([
            'startAngle',
            'endAngle',
            'innerRadius',
            'outerRadius',
            'circumference'
        ], useFinalPosition);
        const rAdjust = this.options.spacing / 2; // This is line where `options` is `null`
        const _circumference = valueOrDefault(circumference, endAngle - startAngle);
        const betweenAngles = _circumference >= TAU || _angleBetween(angle, startAngle, endAngle);
        const withinRadius = _isBetween(distance, innerRadius + rAdjust, outerRadius + rAdjust);
        return betweenAngles && withinRadius;
    }
```

Comment: I tried with `3.x`. Positions (left and right) work fine. I believe this is a bug starting from version `4.x` only. Additionally, I have tried other `4.x` minor versions. But no luck.

Comment: Make sure that `year` is a string when used as `label`; if that's the case, you may try your data in a minimal environment like [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cdgxea4p/)

Comment: That's indeed correct. Thanks for pointing out. However, I have reported this issue on [the GitHub repo](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/11594), too, and respective PRs are open to fixing the problems with non-string values.